# Rest API - unable to update a definition

Tags: c#, rest, arcgis-online

I wasn't quite sure whether to ask this here or in the GIS Stack Exchance. Possibly both. But I feel I'm doing something fundamentally wrong here - the update doesn't seem to be taking effect (when I look in the console afterwards it's still false).

I'm writing a process in C# to update a Feature Layer's definition and make it able to sync. The bits of code I've written so far for other processes (uploading new files and downloading queries) work fine, I'm just having some issues with this one and think I need a few pointers. Official resources can be found on the below links:

[Sync-enabled feature services](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/sync-enabled-feature-services.htm)

[Update Definition (Feature Service)](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/update-definition-feature-service-.htm)

[Update Definition (Feature Layer)](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/update-definition-feature-layer-.htm)

The code I have is:

```
static async Task<string> ReSync(string myToken, string ServiceUrl)
{
    try
    {
        var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("f", "json"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("token", myToken),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("async", "true"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("syncEnabled", "true"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("capabilities", "Query,Editing,Create,Update,Delete,Sync")
        });
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
        var response = await client.PostAsync(ServiceUrl, content);
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return responseString + " <> " + ServiceUrl + " <> " + content;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        return exception.ToString();
    }
}
```

With my ServiceUrl being along the lines of:

> https://servicesX.arcgis.com/MyCompanyID/arcgis/rest/admin/services/MyLayerName/FeatureServer/updateDefinition

The responseString returned (the response, ServiceUrl, and content, in that order) is:

> {"statusURL":"https://servicesX.arcgis.com//MyCompanyID/ArcGIS/rest/admin/services/MyLayerName/FeatureServer/updateDefinition/a-few-numbers-go-here"} <> https://servicesX.arcgis.com/MyCompanyID/arcgis/rest/admin/services/MyLayerName/FeatureServer/updateDefinition <> System.Net.Http.FormUrlEncodedContent

If I do it manually (from the ArcGIS Online console) and record the response in Chrome's DevTools, we get (important bits):

**General**

> Request URL: https://servicesX.arcgis.com/MyCompanyID/arcgis/rest/admin/services/MyLayerName/FeatureServer/updateDefinition
>
> Request Method: POST

**Form Data**

> updateDefinition: {"hasStaticData":false,"capabilities":"Query,Editing,Create,Update,Delete,Sync","editorTrackingInfo":{"enableEditorTracking":false,"enableOwnershipAccessControl":false,"allowOthersToUpdate":true,"allowOthersToDelete":true,"allowOthersToQuery":true,"allowAnonymousToUpdate":true,"allowAnonymousToDelete":true}}
>
> async: true
>
> f: json
>
> token: LotsAndLotsOfCharactersAndStuff

Comment: It has been a while, but why not use the Arcgis package?
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Esri.ArcGISRuntime/

Comment: @RobertPouleijn I'm doing this using SSIS which, I believe, does not support nuget. Great suggestion though!

Comment: Build a console app that does use the package and use fiddler to find out what http calls are made :P